# jquery ui sortable - capture order even if user does not change order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dynamically created list of div elements that I don't know ahead of time how many items there will be, they are defined in a previous step.

I can use jquery ui sortable to order them no problem,and when the user changes anything, the following code gives me the sort order I would like. (just printing out the sort order while debugging, it will be stored in a database when complete.)

```js
$(function() {
               update: function(event, ui) {
                  displayOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                  $("#sortable-result").text (displayOrder);
               }
            });
         });
```

This gives me the string of sortable elements I am expecting in a csv list.

However, I would like to also store the display order if the user does not change anything about the order. Because the list is dynamically created, I don't necessarily know which elements will be there, so I can't assume a default order.

So I  looked at the events from the API and I tried amending to the following code. The create event seems like the only one that might do what I need.

```js
 $(function() {
            $('#sortable-fields').sortable({
               create: function(event, ui) {
                  displayOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                  $("#sortable-result").text (displayOrder);
               },
               update: function(event, ui) {
                  displayOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                  $("#sortable-result").text (displayOrder);
               }
            });
         });
```

However, this just gives me a single value in the csv string of 'sortable-none'.

How can I get the sortable list order both when the user changes the order, and when they do not?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK, having looked at my own question, I'm making this harder than it needs to be.

I previously stated that the sortable list is dynamically loaded. If it's dynamically loaded, this means I must already have the default sort order in a variable or I would not have been able to put them into the sortable list in the first place!

I will leave this here encase anyone else has a similar train of thought with the example of how I have achieved this end.

If my dynamic list came from some prior javascript/jquery:

```js
$.each(SortableItemsArray,function(index, value){
// code to print out sortable elements html here.
$('#sortable-fields').append('some html here')

});


// more code...

$(function() {
               update: function(event, ui) {
                  displayOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
                  $("#sortable-result").text (displayOrder);
               }
            });


// just use the SortableItemsArray var as the default order, as that is where the list came from in the first place.
```